How to clone user accesses from one to another?
We are planning to connect Azure DevOps with Azure AD.
We Know that users, who have correct organization emails in azure DevOps, will inherit all accesses after connection with AAD, however users with external emails eg. gmail or outlook, will unable to login.
I have created all users with organization emails however stacked in access granting step.
Need to copy all access, approvers and custom permissions from one user to another.
Anybody have solution?
Thank you in advance.
Tried too google, no solutions.

Based on your description, you have created all users with organization emails in AAD.

Need to copy all access, approvers and custom permissions from one user to another.

To meet this requirement, you can map the external user accounts(gmail or outlook) to the organization emails after connecting to AAD.
Then the organization emails will get the same access as the external user accounts. And the users can use the Organization emails to access Azure DevOps Organization.
For example: Navigate to Organization Settings -> Microsoft Entra

Here is a doc with the detailed steps: Connect your organization to Microsoft Entra ID

Thank You, will try connection on Monday

Feel free to share the result with us. Thanks

@TutulCkul Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if you have any further questions.
